# Compiler doesn't complain about return type. Why?

Tags: java, compilation

I wrote the following java code, and i expected the compiler would complain about it. but i didn't get any errors. Why is this ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ba ba = new Ba();

        ba.fetchSomeValues();

    }

    public String fetchSomeValues(){
        return "Hello";     
    }

}
```

I am calling the method `fetchSomeValues()` which should return "Hello"  (which is a string), and in the main method i have included `ba.fetchSomeValues();` without initializing it to a `String` variable. The compiler doesn't complain Why is this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to assign return values to variables. You **don't have to** do anything at all with them.

Although it is usually not recommended to just drop some return value of a method.

A counter example might be the `Map`'s `put` method which returns the previous value associated with the key. If you don't care whether there was a previous value or not you just simply ignore the return value.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
test.put(1, "one"); // we don't assign the return value since we don't care
```

So in a nutshell the compiler cannot tell whether you care about return values or not. **It is only a problem if the value is significant in the context you are using the method and you ignore it**.

Comment: Map's put is a very good illustration of why the rule is the way it is. Some methods are called primarily for their side effects, such as adding a key-value pair to a map, but may have potentially useful information some callers could use. It is OK to return that information, and those callers who don't need it can just ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

This is absolutely valid to ignore the return value of a method (although not always recommended).

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can ignore return values as you just found out.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is not specific to Java, it is in fact the norm for all the mainstream (and even those less so) languages of today. Even in FP-languages, where the focus is on side-effect-free functions whose only point is the return value, this is allowed.

You should really ask yourself, Do I want to use a language that forces me to assign every return value? Would that be a convenient language to use?

Comment: I would never use a language that required me to use return values (unless, say, it split side-effect-having functions from return-value-having ones, in which case I have a whole 'nother bag of issues with it) because the code would be littered with `String d = someMethod(); int d_ = someOtherMethod(); double d__ = yetAnother();`

Answer (score 2):

`ba.fetchSomeValues();` **does return the string** `"Hello"`, but since you ain't got any *left var* (for example `String s = ba.fetchSomeValues();`), the object of string, that has the `"Hello"` value, created in the `fetchSomeValues()` method, **just get *unused***.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong in this code.
fetchSomeValues() returns a string but you don't have to assign the value.
Normally you can write String returnedValue = a.fetchSomeValues() but it is not necessary